# запуск Java программы из текущей Java программы

Tags: java, javafx

Я пытаюсь вызвать внутри своей программы, открытие другого jar (артефакта)

Мой код :

```
Platform.runLater(()->{
                try {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec('путь к файлу jar');
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

Но получаю ошибку :

```
CreateProcess error=193, %1 не является приложением Win32
```

**Желаемый файл jar - рабочий, запускается по двойному клику.**

**Путь указан верно, если вбить в проводник все работает.**

Comment: запускайте `java -jar путь-до.jar`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо, это помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При даблклике по файлу windows автоматически, по расширению, находит ассоциированное приложение для запуска этого типа файлов.

Для файлов .jar это java.exe, если java таки установлена или скопирована и ассоциирована вручную.

Без этой ассоциации - команда для запуска java приложения из .jar файла такая:

`путь-до-jre/bin/java -jar путь-до-файла.jar`

Такая же команда поможет в случае запуска из другого java процесса.